# php doctrine createQueryBuilder special character

Tags: doctrine-orm

Database store the value "&You" but the query below doesn't return result

```
$buildQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->where('r.TitreSearch LIKE :term')       
        ->setParameter('term', "%&You%")            
    ;
```

On the other hand if I search "You" I have a result

why doctrine not understand character "&" ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the ampersand character but the query itself.

If you want `LIKE` to match a pattern *within* the column value, you must enclose the search term with percentage signs (i.e. `%term%`). Without the percentage signs, `LIKE` acts just the same as the `=` operator; it looks for an exact match.

Try the following:

```
$term = "&You";
$buildQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->where('r.TitreSearch LIKE :term')
        ->setParameter('term', "%$term%");
```

Comment: Ok, but I can assure you that Doctrine has no problems with the ampersand itself. I just tested in one of my own applications, it works file. Maybe there's a different problem, e.g. the ampersand is (URL-) encoded?

Comment: how to explain that first request in this page with direct string &You not working ? (SQLITE DB)